# Installing Packaging 6.2 Error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I'm trying to install some packages on Sitecore 6.2 solution. I'm receiving a strange packager error:
 “Package generation failed: Root element is missing" . I checked logs and nothing appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitecore’s packager wasn't able to generate a package.

It appears that in the process of generating the zip, it needs to access the temp folder during the creating process.

I meet this error few times and it doesn't work allways to give access just for AppPoolIdentity.If it's not working give access for role Everyone.

[Here](http://firebreaksice.com/sitecore-packager-error-root-element-is-missing/) you find a nice article about this error .

Answer (score 0):

I think a probable reason for this failure could be that you created package of an item or a number of items, but its template might be missing.

Alternatively, please check that your AppPoolIdentity, *(ideally Network Service, to check AppPoolIdentity Name, goto IIS Manager, Application Pools and select the AppPool of your website, and in Action Pane on right side, say Advanced Settings, you will be able to see the Name of Process Model -> Identity)* has read-write rights on C:\Windows\Temp directory.

Do let me know after trying the above two things on your solution

Hope this helps!

Regards,
Varun Shringarpure